# Spotify API - "raw" data class arbitrarily returned for some requests

Tags: r, list, class, spotify

I am compiling data about a set of artists on Spotify - data for each song on each album of each artist. I use a for loop to automate this API request on about 80 different `artists` in the data frame `albums`, then assign a bit of info on each album in `albums` to its list object from the API.

*The problem:* my API call doesn't always return a list object. *Sometimes* it returns an object where `class()` = `raw`.

```
#REQUEST DATA
#------------
library(plyr)
library(httr)
library(lubridate)

collablist <- as.list(NULL)

for(i in 1:nrow(albums)){
  tracks_in_one_album <- as.list(NULL) 

  URI = paste0('https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/', albums$album_uri[i], '/tracks') 
  response = GET(url = URI, add_headers(Authorization = HeaderValue))                
  tracks_in_one_album = content(response) 

  tracks_in_one_album[["album"]]       = albums$album_name[i]
  tracks_in_one_album[["album_artist"]] = albums$artists[i]

  collablist[[i]] <- tracks_in_one_album 
  print(albums$artist_name[i])

}
```

The loop runs for somewhere between 50 and 300 albums before I inevitably get the following message:

```
Error in tracks_in_one_album[["album"]] <- albums$album_name[i] : 
  incompatible types (from character to raw) in subassignment type fix
```

When I assign attempting to assign the character object `albums$album_name[i]` to the API requested object `tracks_in_one_album` when it's a list, I have no issue. But occasionally the object is of a `raw` class. Changing it to a list by encapsulating the `content()` call with `as.list` prevents the error from occurring, but it doesn't really fix the issue because for the requests where the data come in as `raw` instead of as a `list` by default, they're sort of mangled (just a vector with .

The craziest part? This doesn't happen consistently. It could happen for the 4th album of Cat Stevens one time; if I rerun, that Cat Stevens album will be fine and get pulled into R as a `list` but perhaps the second album for Migos will come in `raw` instead.

**My Question** - why are the data not always coming in as a `list` when I make a request? How is it possible that this could be happening in such a non-reproducible way?

Comment: Since you're asking for a single album per request (that plus the inconsistency) my guess is that you're hitting an API limit. Without a reproducible example, however, I can't test it out

Comment: Thanks @jake2389 - I'll give it an hour and break up the request into pieces. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: aaaand you're right @jake2389 - thanks a lot!